# "Face Off" ending of season 4 of Breaking Bad explained

Tags: breaking-bad

It has been a while since I watched Breaking Bad so there's a detail that I don't recall concerning the bomb that Walt planted in the nursing home... weren't there any surveillance cameras in the nursing home? I am thinking that since Hector Salamanca was no more a person of interest to the DEA he wasn't being watched by them... But I mean shouldn't the nursing home have surveillance cameras? If yes, how did Walt manage to escape with that?

Comment: Maybe he took Hector for a walk outside, planted the bomb in his wheelchair and then brought him back. Why would anyone suspect, that the returning resident has a bomb inside?

Comment: @TK-421 he didn't visit him usually plus they are sure that Hector didn't put the bomb... someone must have put it for him.

Comment: There is a discussion about this here: https://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/l97bz/just_a_couple_of_questions_about_face_off/

Answer (score 3):

Well, If I am not mistaken there is a scene where Walt is hiding just outside the window to Salamanca's, which means that is his likely means of ingress as he certainly climbed out the window to hide. This method doesn't risk him being spotted with the exception of any external surveillance, which he very likely cased out beforehand in preparation for his plan and evaded.

Comment: He'd have had to move quickly in casing the place, though, because remember he takes that time to talk Salamanca into accepting a final killing blow to Gus, and he rushed to the nursing home from the parking garage after Gus decides not to get back into the Volvo, thus avoiding the car-bomb.

Comment: Wasn't Walter hiding outside the window only when Tyrus came. Walter could still have walked in the front door the first time he went to see Hector Salamanca. When Salamanca came back from the DEA office, Walter would still have to return to the senior home before Tyrus and Gus arrived.